# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.src'

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras, deep-learning

I try to make a website for predict lung cancer using a tensorflow and deploy using flask. I load a model in the app.py use pickle.
Here's my app.py code

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
# import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)

# model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl", "rb"))
# model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model.h5")

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    str_pred = ''
    # age, gender, yellow_finger, anxiety, peer_pressure, chronic_disease, fatigue, allergy, wheezing, alcohol_consuming, coughing, swallowing_difficulty, chest_pain

    age = int(request.form["age"])
    final_age = (age - 62.08510638) / 46.0211257
    gender = int(request.form["gender"])
    yellow_finger = int(request.form["yellow_finger"])
    anxiety = int(request.form["anxiety"])
    peer_pressure = int(request.form["peer_pressure"])
    chronic_disease = int(request.form["chronic_disease"])
    fatigue = int(request.form["fatigue"])
    allergy = int(request.form["allergy"])
    wheezing = int(request.form["wheezing"])
    alcohol_consuming = int(request.form["alcohol_consuming"])
    coughing = int(request.form["coughing"])
    swallowing_difficulty = int(request.form["swallowing_difficulty"])
    chest_pain = int(request.form["chest_pain"])

    list_data = [gender, final_age, yellow_finger, anxiety, peer_pressure, chronic_disease, fatigue, allergy, wheezing,
                 alcohol_consuming, coughing, swallowing_difficulty, chest_pain]
    list_data = np.array(list_data)

    model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl", "rb"))

    prediction_results = model.predict([list_data])
    prediction_results = prediction_results[0]

    if prediction_results >= 0.5:
        return render_template("index.html", str_pred='Ada kanker paru-paru')
    elif prediction_results < 0.5:
        return render_template("index.html", str_pred='Tidak ada kanker paru-paru')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here's my model

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report

import pickle

df = pd.read_csv('survey_lung_cancer.csv')

df['GENDER'].replace(['M', 'F'], [0, 1], inplace=True)
df['LUNG_CANCER'].replace(['NO', 'YES'], [0, 1], inplace=True)

df = df.drop(['SMOKING', 'SHORTNESS OF BREATH'], axis=1)

df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

def finding_outlier_IQR(df):
  Q1 = df.quantile(0.25)
  Q3 = df.quantile(0.75)
  IQR = Q3 - Q1
  df_final = df[((df < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (df > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR)))]
  return df_final

print(finding_outlier_IQR(df['AGE']))

Q1 = df['AGE'].quantile(0.25)
Q3 = df['AGE'].quantile(0.75)
IQR  = Q3 - Q1

Lower_bound = Q1-1.5*IQR
Upper_bound = Q3+1.5*IQR
print(Lower_bound,Upper_bound)

New_Age= (df['AGE']>Lower_bound) & (df['AGE']<Upper_bound)
filtered_data= df[New_Age]
sns.boxplot(x='AGE', data=filtered_data)

y = filtered_data['LUNG_CANCER']
X = filtered_data.drop('LUNG_CANCER',axis=1)

for i in X.columns[2:]:
    temp=[]
    for j in X[i]:
        temp.append(j-1)
    X[i]=temp
X

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
smote = SMOTE(sampling_strategy='auto', random_state=42)
X, y = smote.fit_resample(X, y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 42, test_size=0.2)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, random_state = 42)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train['AGE'] = scaler.fit_transform(X_train[['AGE']])
X_val['AGE'] = scaler.transform(X_val[['AGE']])
X_test['AGE'] = scaler.transform(X_test[['AGE']])

print(scaler.mean_)
print(scaler.var_)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='relu', input_shape=[13]),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.build()
model.summary()
model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                    epochs=100, batch_size=16,
                    validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
                    shuffle=True)
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print("Test loss:", test_loss)
print("Test accuracy:", test_acc)

y_true = y_test
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_true.round(), y_pred.round())
print("\nConfusion Matrix")
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot=True, cmap='Blues')
plt.xlabel('Predicted', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('True', fontsize=12)


pickle.dump(model, open("model.pkl", "wb"))
```

But, it didn't work. I got an error that their no module keras, but I alreadyinstalledl it.

```
[2023-09-26 20:18:30,267] ERROR in app: Exception on /predict [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "D:\AMIKOM\SKRIPSI\dep_pycharm\app.py", line 39, in predict
    model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl", "rb"))
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.src'
```

I have upgraded tensorflow, keras, etc. But, still got the same error. Can I deploy a neural network model in Flask? Or should I try another language? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Recent versions should have pickle support, but in the past older Keras versions did not support Pickle to serialize its objects (Models).

```
pip install joblib
import joblib

# Save the model
joblib.dump(model, "model.pkl")
joblib.load("model.pkl")
```

Full documentation can be found [here](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/serialization_and_wrappers.html).

To answer your trailing question, Flask should not be a problem if you have set up your environment correctly - I'll add a [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-easily-deploy-machine-learning-models-using-flask-b95af8fe34d4) to the medium article I found when researching this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of Keras. Then try to update the keras to latest version. Pickle version 4.0 needs Keras version >= 2.13.0.

To update keras version open CMD and activate your environment then uninstall the current version of keras using the folliwing code

pip uninstall keras

After uninstalling try to install the latest keras version using

pip install keras==2.14.0

Comment: The problem is not about updating this module. OP said: *I have upgraded tensorflow, **keras**, etc. But, still got the same error.*

Answer (score 0):

I too have started to face this issue when working with `tfx=1.8.13` which needed `keras-tuner < 2`. New versions of `keras-tuner` was getting picked up, which also installed currently under experiment [keras-core](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-core) library as well.

In my case the fix was to add `keras-tuner<=1.3.5` dependency in `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a classification model as well for brain disease classification. I used the model from this repository: https://github.com/ZFTurbo/classification_models_3D

And then I got the same problem as yours. I tried to search on the internet and it said that it might due to my python version (that it had to be python 3.9). However, after I tried to check the repository again, the creator has stated the requirements for the tensorflow and keras version we have to use.

Apparently, it will only work with:

```
tensorflow>=2.13.0,<=2.15.0
keras==2.13.1
keras_applications==1.0.8
```

To have this version of tensorflow and keras, you can just do
`pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.13`

When you're upgrading the tensorflow, your keras will also be automatically upgraded to 2.13. And my python version is Python 3.8.10.

I hope this will also work for you!