# AWS Lambda is unable to find keras when deploying image, but only sometimes?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, keras, aws-lambda

I'm building lambdas to interact with Sagemaker behind an API GW.

Yesterday, I worked with an app.py with requirements.txt and a dockerfile to deploy a lambda function. This normally went fine. We also have about a dozen lambdas like this in production, that are not throwing errors. However, because I wanted to use a python 3.9 functionality I've changed to the python 3.9 dockerfile.

Today, with seemingly no changes to the requirements.txt file my lambda is showing a runtime error because it cannot find Keras. Which it could find fine, yesterday.

Here's my requirements.txt:

```
tensorflow==2.8.0
keras==2.8.*
requests==2.28.2
pandas
scikit-learn
joblib==1.2
langdetect==1.0.9
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
urllib3<2
dill
protobuf<3.20
```

and here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.9

COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

COPY requirements.txt  .

RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}" --verbose

CMD [ "app.lambda_handler"]
```

I am using ECR and use the following deployment script, redacted to hide account id:

```
docker build -t project-foo . --no-cache --progress=plain &> build.log
docker tag project-foo:latest <aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/project-foo:latest
docker push <aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/project-foo:latest

aws lambda update-function-code --function-name project-foo-test --image-uri <aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/project-foo:latest > update_response.json
```

I get the following run time error when I invoke my function (which worked fine yesterday!)

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'keras.src'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "<requestid>",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: `keras==2.8.*`.  I'm guessing that this can potentially choose different minor versions of keras, which causes the problem.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/77180527/494134

Comment: *"However, because I wanted to use a python 3.9 functionality I've changed to the python 3.9 dockerfile"* How? What was it before? Does it work again if you undo this change?

Comment: _because it cannot find Keras_ No.  The problem is specifically with `keras.src` submodule, not `keras`.

Comment: @JohnGordon Hey John. It's happening regardless of whether I pin it to any minor versions. I've tried building every version between 2.6 and 2.14. Keras does not have a src module (it goes straight to keras.preprocessing.*) so I'm not sure how / what is adding it. I've taken a look in the container image and sure enough, Keras is right there and running my app works locally.

Comment: @DeepSpace I need the 3.9+ version because I use functionality only present in 3.9+ like the cache decorator. To clarify, yesterday this worked. Today, with no changes. Not so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to fix this after a lot of debugging, inspecting images and what not.

The problem was with two tokenizers I was trying to import. It was not for importing keras or tensorflow. These tokenizers are binary files that I was loading that referenced keras.

Tokenizer 1 was new - made with tensorflow 2.13, while tokenizer 2 was older (probably made with tensorflow 2.1, python 3.6). Upon loading, they required Keras.src and Keras_preprocessing (a legacy Keras library for python 3.6 and lower) respectively. Exactly how is not something I'm sure about. Since the models are hosted on a separate endpoint, this was never relevant (a keras tokenizer is in essence just a giant lookup table that convert words to numerical indexes).

I've managed to bypass this requirement by saving the tokenizers to json and loading them separately, which dumps the tokenizers to a plain, almost agnostic format. The downside is that my tokenizers are large at 80 MB each in their json definition.

In code, my fix involved running the following snippet to convert joblib to json:

```
tokenizer = joblib.load("artifacts/tokenizer.joblib")
tokenizer_json = tokenizer.to_json()
with open(f'artifacts/tokenizer.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(tokenizer_json, ensure_ascii=False))
```

inside app.py:

```
with open(f'artifacts/tokenizer.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.tokenizer_from_json(data)
```

Exactly how this became an issue or why it worked before is still a mystery to me. I hope this helps anyone encountering the same error.